Button adding event has no effect
I am studying html, css, and js.
Add click events to the arrow buttons of flickity,
I used addEventListener. However, I got the following error.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at index.js:3:6

I'm still a beginner so I don't know where I'm going wrong.

html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Calendar</h1>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "pageDots": false }'>
            <div class="carousel-cell">1</div>
            <div class="carousel-cell">3</div>
            <div class="carousel-cell">4</div>
            <div class="carousel-cell">5</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

css
.carousel-cell {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 48px;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
}


.carousel .flickity-prev-next-button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

 .carousel .flickity-prev-next-button.previous {
    left: 250px;
}

.carousel .flickity-prev-next-button.next {
    right: 250px;    
}

javascript
const btn = document.querySelector(".carousel .flickity-prev-next-button");


btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Hello")
});


Where is .flickity-prev-next-button?

It is not in the html file, but when I looked at the dev tool, I found that it was created as a child element of the carousel element.

If it's created by flickity, you need to make sure index.js only executed after element created.

Does that mean that index.js runs faster than flickty-created elements?

it does not run "faster". With the exception of the usage of web workers, JS will only run in one thread.  That means that JS can't run multiple things at the same time, only after each other. That means that your index.js is simply just read before the other script`

@tacoshy If you look at the html code, read <script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity @2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js">></script> before index.js.
The first thing to read is flickity.pkgd.min.js, but the first thing to complete is index.js?

@ybybyb not necessarily. My educated guess is that the flickity script delays the script by using something like window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...) Your own script is not delayed and will be executed immediately.

@tacoshy Oh, thank you. It's hard, but I think I understand a little bit.

Your JavaScript is likely executed before Flickity elements have been added to the DOM. Flickity takes a bit of time to initialize, and the .flickity-prev-next-button elements might not yet exist when your code runs. This is indicated by the error message, as your selector returns a null object (i.e. nothing found).
Consider using Flickity's "ready" event to execute code after those dynamic elements are added to the DOM.

ready
Triggered after Flickity has been activated.

Also, querySelector selects only the "first Element within the document that matches the specified selector," but there are two button elements. I used querySelectorAll to select both buttons and iterated through them using forEach to add event listeners.
Also see Flickity complete event when initialized with HTML, although that example uses the "active" event rather than "ready".


Flickity.prototype.on('ready', function() {

  const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel .flickity-prev-next-button");

  btns.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("Clicked");
    });
  });

  console.log('Loaded');

});
.carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 48px;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel .flickity-prev-next-button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel .flickity-prev-next-button.previous {
  left: 250px;
}

.carousel .flickity-prev-next-button.next {
  right: 250px;
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">

<h1>My Calendar</h1>

<div class="header">
  <div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "pageDots": false }'>
    <div class="carousel-cell">1</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">3</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">4</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

</div>




Alternatively, you could bind the event listener to a more static element (one that is not added later). See Adding an event listener to an element that doesn't exist yet in vanilla javascript and the example below:


// the carousel element exists prior to Flickity initialization, so no need to wait.
const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel");

carousel.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  let element = event.target;
  // is the clicked element part of a prev/next button?
  if (element.closest(".flickity-prev-next-button")) {
    console.log("Clicked");
  }
});
.carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 48px;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel .flickity-prev-next-button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel .flickity-prev-next-button.previous {
  left: 250px;
}

.carousel .flickity-prev-next-button.next {
  right: 250px;
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">

<h1>My Calendar</h1>

<div class="header">
  <div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "pageDots": false }'>
    <div class="carousel-cell">1</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">3</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">4</div>
    <div class="carousel-cell">5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

</div>



